# Did any of the Motorola 68k processors have performance counters?

Tags: 68000

Did any of the Motorola 68k processors have performance counters or anything similar that could be used for cycle-level code timing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing like this up to at least 68060 CPUs.
From the other side, manual cycle counting for 68000 (the first CPU in the family) is relatively easy.

Answer (score 1):

For manual cycle-counting (which is pretty much your only option here...), many cycle-count tables exist.  For example, the famous YACHT.TXT file, a copy of which can be found at http://nemesis.hacking-cult.org/MegaDrive/Documentation/Yacht.txt (and many other places)